# API-Platform graphql: one to many relations creates sql statements for every dataset

Tags: php, performance, symfony, graphql

We got the issue, that we have a lot of relations and a lot of data.
Now we tried out api-platform with graphql implementation and found out that for every relation there will be a single sql statement created for each entry we fetch.
That costs a lot of queries, we had a own implementation for graphql where we implemented almost the same functionality but looked to fetch all relational data with a single sql statement.
Is that a known issue?

We expected that there will be one single statement witch fetches data including relational data in a single query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.